# Как преобразовать числа в списке в целые числа?

Tags: python, строки, int

Допустим,есть список:

```
r = ['Alica', '884', 'Bread', '231']
```

Нужно,чтобы числа преобразовались в числа,а не были строками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такой вариант устроит?

```
r = ['Alica', '884', 'Bread', '231']

n = [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in r]

print(n)
```

правда есть недостатки - работает только с натуральными числами, состоящими только из цифр

а вот более универсальный метод:

```
r = ['Alica', '884', 'Bread', '-231', '2.1e5', '3.1415']

n = []

for i in r:
    # пробуем преобразовать в float
    try:
        value = float(i)
        n.append(int(value) if value == int(value) else value)
    except ValueError:
        n.append(i)

print(n)
```